# About handling a custom Event

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, events, event-handling

If I have an Event like this:

```
' <summary>
' Event raised when conversion progress changes.
' </summary>
Public Shared Event PercentDone(ByVal percent As Integer)

Sub(...)
    CoreConverter.StartInfo.FileName = CoreConverter_Location
    CoreConverter.Start()

    While Not CoreConverter.HasExited

        If ChrW(CoreConverter.StandardOutput.Read) = "*" Then
            progress += 1
            RaiseEvent PercentDone(progress)
        End If

    End While

    CoreConverter.Close()
    RaiseEvent Exited()

End sub
```

How I can write the event handler in other class (For example in default Form1 Class) as this:

```
Sub Converter_Progress(Progress As Integer) Handles CoreConverter.PercentDone
     ' Some code...
End Sub
```

...Instead adding manually the handler like this else:

```
AddHandler CoreConverter.PercentDone, AddressOf Converter_Progress
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use the `Handles` keyword, you need to declare the variable as a field in your class (at the class level, not local to any method) and do so using the `WithEvents` keyword.  For instance:

```
Public Class Test
    Private WithEvents Converter As New CoreConverter()

    Sub Converter_Progress(Progress As Integer) Handles Converter.PercentDone
        ' Some code...
    End Sub    
End Class
```

However, I should mention that, even for custom events, it is recommended that you follow the .NET convention for event handler delegates, where there are always two arguments: the sender and the event args.  The easiest way to do that is to use the generic `EventHandler(Of T)` delegate, for instance:

```
Public Class PercentDoneEventArgs
    Inherits EventArgs

    Public Property Progress As Integer
End Class

Public Class CoreConverter
    Public Event PercentDone As EventHandler(Of PercentDone)

    ' ...
End Class
```

Then, your event handler method would look like this:

```
Sub Converter_Progress(sender As Object, e As PercentDoneEventArgs) Handles Converter.PercentDone
    ' ...
End Sub
```

Comment: Thankyou, but then there is no way to do it without instancing the class?, my class does not have IDisposable, I know how to create a Dispose procedure but what I don't know is if in this case is necessary because I need to instande the class to handle the event as I want. and other question if I don't ask too much, I've followed your instructions about the creation of events, but the value "Nothing" is correct for the "e" variable?, just I don't have any more to pass than the progress value so...I've putted a "nothing" here: RaiseEvent PercentDone(progress, Nothing)

Comment: You do not need to immediately instantiate an object as part of the declaration.  You can simply declare the variable `WithEvents`, leaving it initially set to `Nothing`, then you can set it to reference any object you want at a later time.  You can change which object it references as often as you like, but, obviously, it can only reference one object at a time.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would have to inherit the base class that has the event then you can overwrite the event so then your new class gets the event, and your new class redirects the event to the base class.  Or are you needing something else?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use "WithEvents" when declaring your class-level instance (in your case "CoreConverter").  For example:

```
Private WithEvents CoreConverter As MyConverterType
```